# Silverlight OOB throws internal script error

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I got a commercial app that is working fine on most machines OOB.

I got just 1 user who gets following error when he launches OOB version (note that in his browsers it works fine).

[image]

Sorry for russian language, but his machine is in Russian.

Generally it says that there is an error and that silverlight is not installed.
I did install latest (5) Silverlight version and it didn't fix the problem.

What could this be?

Comment: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SilverlightServiceClient

Comment: Care to elaborate your link?

Comment: Is the silverlight plugin enabled in browser, also (if it is IE - thats what it looks like), can you try installing FF and try it with it ?

Comment: Its Out Of Browser version (OOB). It does work in IE,FF and chrome. It doesnt work in OOB

Comment: Can we see the js line with `document.gelElementById(...)` ?

Comment: Could you please specify the OS at this machine and is the OOB is a Trusted Application?

Comment: Sevenate, its Windows XP. OOB is not a Trusted App.

Comment: Tonio, about JS, I am not sure what kind of javascript is being run by OOB launcher? how do I find out.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete stab-in-the-dark, it might not work for you at all.

On a previous project we had an issue with a Silverlight application not working for a few users.  We found a post on the Silverlight forums which mentioned that the problem was ultimately due to a corrupt user profile.  However, as Microsoft have now closed the Silverlight forums, I can no longer find this article.

It turns out that the fix was to open a Command Prompt and run the following:

```
reg export "HKCU\Control Panel\International" international.reg
reg import international.reg
```

Obviously, as this involves modifying the registry, suitable care should be taken.

Comment: thanks Luke, will give it a try. forums closed? didnt they promise to have SL support till 2020?

Comment: @ValentinKuzub: MS have closed the forums at forums.silverlight.net, which was where we found the fix for our problem.  Support for Silverlight may well continue until 2020 but I guess that doesn't stop MS from closing a forums site.